# LightSwitch 2013 HTML Client - SSMS Generated Foreign key column missing when pulling it into LightSwitch as a relationship?

Tags: lightswitch-2013

Creating a foreign key in SSMS and updating the datasource in LS pulls in the relationship but hides the foreign key column?

From what I think I am getting from reading forums is , it seems to come down to :
1 - Creating a foreign key on SSMS and pulling it in to LS will hide the foreign key column. BUT cascading delete will work. 
2 - Creating a foreign key (relationship) in LS will show the associated column. BUT cascading has to be done in the LS code programmatically.

I need the SSMS cascading AND to see all table fields for every table in LS. Is this not possible?

If the foreign key column is even named something else, where and how do i get to it, and keep the SSMS cascade?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Washington help me understand this better. When I create an EF model from SQL Server, I get the option "Include foreign key columns in the model" when selecting the tables I want to use.  You don't get that in LightSwitch, but the foreign key column can be updated. In my case, when I initialized the fields of the detail (the  'ld' prefix) screen I was calling with "BeforeShown", I had to set this detail screens (newExerciseMeasure) copy of the master with this line " newExerciseMeasure.setMbsaDailyLog(screen.MbsaDailyLog);"

myapp.showAddEditMbsaDailyLogDetail(null, global_MemberNo, null, null, null, null, null, {
            beforeShown: function (addNewScreen) {
               var newExerciseMeasure = new myapp.MbsaDailyLogDetail;
                newExerciseMeasure.ldCreatedBy = global_MemberNo;
                newExerciseMeasure.ldUpdatedBy = global_MemberNo;
                newExerciseMeasure.ldRecordNo = 0;
                newExerciseMeasure.ldSourceType = 0;
                newExerciseMeasure.ldSourceNo = 0;
                newExerciseMeasure.ldDateCreated = new Date();
                newExerciseMeasure.ldDateUpdated = new Date();
                newExerciseMeasure.ldUOMNo = 0;
                newExerciseMeasure.ldValue = "";
                newExerciseMeasure.ldNotes = "";
                newExerciseMeasure.ldStatus = "";
                newExerciseMeasure.setMbsaDailyLog(screen.MbsaDailyLog);
                addNewScreen.MbsaDailyLogDetail = newExerciseMeasure;
              }

```
    });
```